# Preparing data for Chaboche Model in ANSYS

Tags: ansys

Can i transfer somehow my hysteresis data to ANSYS Chaboche model if the hystereses are not connected? How to properly defined it in ANSYS if I have Ramberg-Osgood prediction equation? What should I do, please help!
[image: true plastic strain vs true stress]

Comment: Does Ansys have a help entry about handling data?

Comment: There is no problem with entering data. Please read my description carefully.

Comment: Hysteresis data is ... data...

Comment: The problem is that hystereses are not connected and ANSYS connects points randomly. Please, anyone can help?